# Extract value of one array from another array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a few arrays as shown below.

```
$a1 = "apple"
$a2 = "ball"
$a3 = "cat"
$a4 = "dog"
$a5 = "egg"
```

Now, I am trying to store the values of the above arrays in a separate array as shown below.

```
$array = @()
for($i = 1; $i -le 5; $i++) {$array += "$" + "a$i"}
```

Now $array give me the following

```
PS C:\> $array
$a1
$a2
$a3
$a4
$a5
PS C:\>
```

What I want now is if I can extract the value of `array $a1`which is apple, instead of the array's `$array` value `$a1`. I would like to extract the value "**apple**" of `$a1` from `$array`. Somebody who has done this before, can you please shed some light on this. Thanks.

Comment: `$a1 = "apple"` is not an array

Comment: Yes 4c74356b41. You are right. My bad. The base type for $a1 is indeed System.Object. Thanks for pointing that out. The below answer works for me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for($i = 1; $i -le 5; $i++) {$array += Get-Variable ("a" + $i)}
```

this would get variables a1,a2... and store them into array